# Compound Binomial - Exponential process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-walk

**Problem:**

I have a sum of $N$ random variables $X_i$, where $N$ is distributed according to a binomial distribution and the $X_i$ are independent and identically distributed according to an exponential distribution. 
I would like to get the pdf of the sum

$$ Y_N = X_1 + X_2 + \dots + X_N. $$

If I write the pmf of $N$ as
$$ p_n = {N \choose n} p^n q^{N-n}$$
and the pdf of the $X_i$ as 
$$ f(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x},$$
How can I get the pdf $p(y)$ of $Y_N$?

**Attempt:**

I gather this is called a compound process. I read about it somewhat in Feller: the section is "Sum of a Random Number of Random Variables", but he does not mix discrete and continuous random variables.
I think this is just a discrete time random walk where the steps are exponentially distributed.

I think I can condition something like 
$$\text{Prob}(Y_N = y) = \sum_{n=0}^N \text{Prob}(N=n)\text{Prob}(X_1 + \dots +X_n = y),$$
and this will become

$$p(y) = \sum_{n=1}^N p_n f^{n*}(y),$$

but I'm not actually sure how to write the $n$-fold convolution of exponentials (although this should be a Gamma distribution I think).
So, first interjection: is it this?

$$ f^{n*}(y) = \int dx_1\dots dx_n f(x_1)f(x_2-x_1)f(x_3-x_2-x_1)\dots f(y-x_n-\dots x_1)?$$

or is it this?

$$ f^{n*}(y) = \int dx_1\dots dx_n f(y-x_n)f(x_n-x_{n-1})\dots f(x_2-x_1)f(x_1)?$$

Then I know I can take a laplace transform to simplify the convolution (although I'm not sure what the convolution should look like exactly yet), to get something like

$$ p(s) = \sum_{n=0}^N p_n f(s)^n$$

Does this make sense? Then this is the probability generating function of $p_n$ evaluated at $f(s)$:

$$ G(z) = \langle z^n \rangle|_{z=f(s)} = \sum_{n=0}^N z^n p_n |_{z=f(s)}$$

So the mgf for $ p(y)$ is the pgf for $p_n$ evaluated at the mgf for f(x): Is this correct?

(using [this link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/297711/what-is-the-difference-between-moment-generating-function-and-probability-genera) to keep my words straight)

Following through, the pgf of the binomial distribution $p_n$ is

$$ G(z) = \sum_{i=0}^N  {N \choose i} (zp)^i q^{N-i} = (zp + q)^N,$$

(verified correct [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Probability_Generating_Function_of_Binomial_Distribution))
and the mgf of the exponential distribution $f(x)$ is

$$ f(s) = \int_0^\infty dx \lambda e^{(s-\lambda)x} = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda -s} $$

(verified correct [here](https://www.statlect.com/probability-distributions/exponential-distribution#hid6)).
So the mgf for $p(y)$ will be

$$ p(s) = (p\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-s}+q)^N. $$

So for example the mean value of $Y$ should be

$$\mu_Y = \frac{d}{ds}(p\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-s}+q)^N|_{s=0} =   N (p\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-s}+q)^{N-1} p\frac{\lambda}{(\lambda-s)^2}|_{s=0} = Np\lambda^{-1}. $$
(Fixed an error thanks to Clement)

The probability distribution should be the inverse fourier transform of the characteristic function $p(s=ik)$:

$$p(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dk}{2\pi} e^{-iky}(\frac{p\lambda}{\lambda-ik}+p)^N$$

Any thoughts on this integral are appreciated !

Comment: This is correct. This is the simplest way - to find mgf of $Y_N$ from pgf of $N$.

Comment: @NCh can you comment on the proper way for me to write the convolution integral of $N$ distributions? And any idea why I get a negative mean value for Y?

Comment: @kevinkayaks Your differentiation has a mistake.

Comment: Oh I see that now! I missed a minus. Thanks @ClementC.

Comment: You can check that the expectation is correct: $$\mathbb{E}[Y_N]= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y_N\mid N]]= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\sum_{k=1}^N X_k\mid N]]= \mathbb{E}[N\cdot \frac{1}{\lambda}] = \frac{np}{\lambda}$$

Comment: Thanks Clement- a bit confused on the last equality -- I think this is Wald's theorem which I will have to study. I know the name but not the idea. I have one last problem: which is to get from the mgf to the pdf. Can I send $s$ to $is$ and take the inverse Fourier transform with respect to s? That would lead to a nasty integral. Or can I get at it at different way?

Comment: @kevinkayaks Why go through the characteristic function? You can take the inverse Laplace transform of the MGF (instead of the inverse Fourier transform of the characteristic function).

Comment: Unsure how to proceed: does this become an N-fold  convolution of the Laplace transform of the function raised to the Nth power in $p(s)$?

Comment: @kevinkayaks No. You have computed the MGF (this is also called the Laplace transform), $p(s)$; you can compute the inverse Laplace transform of $p$ to get the pdf. It is going to be messy, though, I fear.

Comment: Oh I see. I thought you were suggesting a way around the integral. I'll give it a go. One option is to binomial expand the pmf and integrate that. I think it gives a sum of gamma functions, more or less. Thanks again

Comment: @kevinkayaks $f^{n*}(y)=\iint f(x_1)f(x_2)\ldots f(x_{n-1}) f(y-x_1-x_2-\ldots-x_{n-1})\,dx_1\,dx_2\ldots dx_{n-1}$. 
And you can prove that sum of i.i.d. exponential r.v.'s is Gamma distributed without n-fold convolution, only from convolution of two pdf's, by induction.

Comment: Thanks @NCh. I realized how to get that from $\int dx_1\dots dx_n f(x_1)\dots f(x_n) \delta(y-x_1-\dots-x_n)$, more or less. I still have to work out how the integration limits work in $f^{n*}(y)$. The $x_i$ are all rearranged to have $x_i<x_{i+1}$ and the integral over $dx_i$ has to run from $0$ to $x_{i+1}$, I think. I'm not sure on this point. I realize from the Ross book it's easy to get that result from induction, but I'm just self-studying statistics and trying to get fundamental concepts worked out

Comment: @kevinkayaks The unique fundamental concept here is that a sum of two independent gamma distributed r.v.'s with the same scale (or rate) parameter is also gamma distributed. This fact simply follows from convolution of two gamma pdf's (as well as from mgf's etc) and covers all cases when there are more than two summands.

Comment: Yes, but that's bottom up. For general understanding I'd also like to be able to go from the top down: $\int dx_1 \dots dx_n f(x_1)\dots f(x_n) \delta(y-x_1-\dots-x_n).$ It's unclear to me how the integration limits become linked in order to express the gamma distribution, as in $x_1 \in (0,x_2)$, $x_2 \in (0,x_3)$, and so on.

Comment: Consider $n=3$. $$\int dx_1\,dx_2 f(x_1)f(x_2)f(y-x_1-x_2)=\int\limits_0^y \lambda e^{-\lambda x_1} dx_1 \int\limits_0^{y-x_1}\lambda e^{-\lambda x_2} dx_2$$ since we integrate over $x_1,x_2>0$, $y-x_1-x_2>0$. Or equivalent $0<x_1<y$, $0<x_2<y-x_1$.
For $n=4$ you will get $0<x_1<y$, $0<x_2<y-x_1$, $0<x_3<y-x_1-x_2$. And so on.