# MGF of a Binomial-Exponential Compound Distribution

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-walk, moment-generating-functions

I have the following compound binomial-exponential distribution:

$Z \sim \text{Binom}(N,p)$

$p = (1 - e^{-\lambda_{1}Y})$

$Y \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda_0)$

$N=1$

I am attempting to follow the derivation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3038793/compound-binomial-exponential-process) to derive the Moment Generating Function (MGF) of this rather nasty distribution in order to derive the PDF. However, I am confused as to exactly how I determine the MGF with my additional parameter $p$.

**Attempt at a solution**:

I know that, for this distribution, the expectation value should be:

$E(E(Z|Y)) = \frac{N \lambda_1}{\lambda_{0} + \lambda_{1}}$

which I can use to check the solution.

From the same solution as linked, it is stated (paraphrasing):

*'the Moment Generating Function (MGF) for the compound Probability Density Function (PDF), Z, is the Probability Generating Function (PGF) of the Binomial distribution evaluated at the MGF for Exponential Distribution'*

the PGF of the binomial distribution is given by (see link):

$G(z)=\sum_{i=0}^{N}\left(\begin{array}{c}
N \\
i
\end{array}\right)(z p)^{i} q^{N-i}=(z p+q)^{N}$

The moment generating function of an exponential distribution is (see link):

$f(t)=\int_{0}^{\infty} d x \lambda e^{(t-\lambda_{0}) x}=\frac{\lambda_{0}}{\lambda_{0}-t}$

Now, I am unsure how I bring $p$ into the picture, in particular whether I substitute in this case for $p$ and $q$. I am also not sure in this case what $z$ should be.

Can anyone offer a hint/guidance as to how to proceed?

**Attempt at a Solution:**

The moment generating function of this distribution is given, as stated below, by conditioning on $Y=y$. Lets rename the constants, $\lambda_{0}=a$ and $\lambda_{1}=b$, for the sake of ease of reading:

$\begin{array}{l}
M(t)=\int a e^{-a y}\left(\left(1-e^{-b y}\right) e^{t}+e^{-b y}\right) d y= \\
a\left(\frac{\left(e^{t}-1\right) e^{y(-(a+b))}}{a+b}-\frac{e^{t-a y}}{a}\right) \end{array}$

We now have to evaluate this integral at $\infty$ and zero.

First at infinity:

$I_{\infty} = a\left(\frac{\left(e^{t}-1\right) e^{-\inf((a+b))}}{a+b}-\frac{e^{t-a\inf}}{a}\right) \rightarrow 0 $

Then at zero:

$I_{0} = a\left(\frac{\left(e^{t}-1\right)}{a+b}-\frac{e^{t}}{a}\right)$

So:

$M(t) = I_{\infty} - I_{0} = a\left(\frac{e^{t}}{a} - \frac{\left(e^{t}-1\right)}{a+b}\right)$

However, now I attempt to verify with what I know:

$\frac{\partial M(t)}{\partial t}\rvert_{t=0} = \mu$

$\frac{\partial M(t)}{\partial t} = \frac{be^{t}}{b+a}$

which recovers the expected mean:

$\mu = \frac{b}{b+a}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe we start with untangling some confusion.

The probability generating function is your function $G(z)$ and it is actually defined via expectation: $\mathbb E[z^X]$. However, what you are looking for is the moment generating function, which is similarly defined as follows:
$$M_X(t):=\mathbb E[exp(Xt)]=\int_{\mathbb R}exp(xt)f_X(t)dt$$

We can indeed use the tower property that you mentioned.

We first note: $$M_Z(t)=(1-p+p\cdot exp(t))^N$$
if $p$ where NOT random. How do we get rid of the randomness? That is doable via tower property:

$$M_Z(t)=\mathbb E[exp(Zt)]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[exp(Zt)|Y]]$$

To compute that look at the quantity: $\mathbb E[exp(Zt)|Y=y]$. This has the form as mentioned above, but with p defined as given. Now this is a function $g(y)$ of y, a number for each fixed y. To compute the outer expectation with respect to the given exponential distribution, just integrate with respect to the exponential density:
$$M_Z(t)=\int_{\mathbb R^+}g(y)\lambda_0 \exp(-\lambda_0 y)dy.$$

If you need more explicit help, feel free to ask. Hope this helps without spoiling the fun ;)

EDIT: I just add my computation for the moment generating function for $N=1$. We keep in mind, how the exponential distribution is defined and we will utilize that to keep us from computing any integrals explicitly.

$$M_Z(t)=\mathbb E_Y[\left(1+(1-e^{-\lambda_1 Y})(e^t-1)\right)]$$
$$=\int_0^\infty\left(1+(1-e^{-\lambda_1 y})(e^t-1)\right)\lambda_0e^{-\lambda_0 y}dy$$
$$=\int_0^\infty\lambda_0e^{-\lambda_0y}dy+(e^t-1)\int_0^\infty(1-e^{-\lambda_1y})\lambda_0e^{-\lambda_0 y}dy$$
$$=1+(e^t-1)\left(1-\frac{\lambda_0}{\lambda_0+\lambda_1}\cdot\int_0^\infty(\lambda_0+\lambda_1)e^{-(\lambda_0+\lambda_1) y}dy\right)$$
$$=1+(e^t-1)\left(1-\frac{\lambda_0}{\lambda_0+\lambda_1}\right)
=1+(e^t-1)\cdot\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_0+\lambda_1}$$
$$=\frac{\lambda_0}{\lambda_0+\lambda_1}+e^t\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_0+\lambda_1}=q+e^t(1-q)$$

However using the binomial theorem for other values of $N$, will get us to $$M_Z(t)=(q+(1-q)e^t)^N$$
which just shows, that the $Z$ is binomial again, i.e. $Z\sim Bin(N,1-q)$. In other words, randomizing the success parameter of a binomial distribution with an exponential parameter does not change the type of distribution.

This explains also, why the inverse Fourier-transform yields something constant. The random variable $Z$ is just discrete and thus has no (absolutely continuous) density (with respect to Lebesgue-measure).

Comment: Thank you for the reply! 

Assuming I understood you correctly:
$M_{Z}(t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{+}} g(y) \lambda_{0} \exp \left(-\lambda_{0} y\right) d y = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{+}} (e^{-\lambda_{1}y} + (1 - e^{-\lambda_{1}y})e^{t})^{N}(\lambda_{0}e^{-\lambda_{0}y}).dy$

Comment: yes, that looks like it ;)

Comment: I have made a second attempt, there is an error in the equation I gave there: $e^{t}$ should be $e^{yt}$. I have made an second attempt, but the result is nothing like I expect for some reason. Can you comment?

Comment: Why would it be $\exp(yt)$? 
I get as a result of using $exp(t)$ for $N=1$, as it should be, $$M_Z(t)=q+\exp(t)(1-q)$$ where $q:=\frac{\lambda_0}{\lambda_0+\lambda_1}$. This is consistent with taking the derivative at 1, and comparing it to $\mathbb E[Z]=N\cdot(1-q)$.

Comment: When I tried this, I obtained: $M(t) =\int_{\mathbb{R}^{+}}\left(e^{-\lambda_{1} y}+\left(1-e^{-\lambda_{1} y}\right) e^{t}\right) \left(\lambda_{0} e^{-\lambda_{0} y}\right) \cdot d y = \lambda_{0}(\frac{e^t}{\lambda_{0}} - \frac{(-1 + e^t)}{(\lambda_{0} + \lambda_{1})})$, which does indeed yield $\mu = \frac{\lambda_{1}}{\lambda_{0}+\lambda_{1}}$. However, I noticed that the characteristic function results in a constant p.d.f, which is not what I expect.

Comment: I added something to my answer. From the mgf of Z is clear that Z is a discrete random variable and can thus not have a density.

Comment: I agree with all the above - thanks for your help! However, I have realised from this that I have a different question to that posted, which is my fault. The question should be: 'what is the p.d.f of the variable Y given that Z=1' . You have helped me a great deal with this - I shall add in the follow-up question as a link later on.

Comment: New question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4281398/finding-the-pdf-of-a-conditional-binomial-exponential-compound-distribution